# Where can I buy elemental resistance potions?

Tags: torchlight-2

I've purchased potions of fire and ice resistance, but now I am out and need to buy more.  However, I can't remember where I bought them the first time.  I checked the Imperial Camp and the town after that, but have had no luck and I don't feel like backtracking to the beginning of the game.  Any help on where these potions can be bought would be nice.

**Update:**

So I got tired of getting my arse burned (literally) by the three sisters, so I town-hopped all the way back to the Estherian Enclave where I finally found a merchant who sells all resistance potions.  It's nice to know where I can buy them now, but do I really have to travel all the way back here every time I run out?  If so, it looks like I will be building up a huge stockpile.

Comment: I never found those potions of much use really, then again elite mode is the only mode I seem to play on, getting hit usually results in a one shot kill. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy them in the Estherian Enclave (First Town you bump into.)
They are located at the General Goods merchant in that town,

Yes, you will literally have to run back to the enclave to get the potions everytime, although before NG+ you can warp there easily, so do not worry about it too much if you need the pots.

-Look at the pic if you have no idea where to find her in the town.
[image]